# How to prevent fragment recreating when conditionally navigating to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I have two fragments A and B.
A is a form which contains `EditText`s and one value need to be selected from fragment B.
When using navigation component after selecting item from B and when conditionally navigating to A , `EditText`s values are gone. The fragment is recreated. How to prevent this?

My intention is to get value from B to A without recreating A

Comment: Please show the code you have done for loading fragment

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its difficult to give you a straight answer, but here are some general ideas

1) [Add fragment A to the backstack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addtobackstack) this will persist it when you return from Fragment B

2) [Find fragment A by its tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager#findfragmentbytag) and if it exists do not create a new Fragment A when returning to it